# Is the polarity of a polarized capacitor fixed irrespective of the direction of current?

Tags: passive-networks

If I have a circuit as shown below, does it mean that the polarity of capacitor is fixed(irrespective of the direction of current through it)? I have to write the differential equation for this network and then find other quantities. So, the sign of voltage drop (in the equation) across the capacitor depends on this information.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgZoQl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Thanks!

Comment: You have already accepted an answer, so I won't write another one. But I just want to point out that the polarity of the voltage across a capacitor and the direction of current through it are completely independent parameters. You can charge and discharge a capacitor (current in both directions) without ever reversing the voltage across it.

Comment: My question was theoretical, which would help me decide the sign of voltage drop across the capacitor in the differential equation (using KVL). If you could shed some light on that, please do so.

Comment: @akshayk07: Double-click the capacitor in the editor. You can select the type in one of the drop-downs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polarized capacitors do not tolerate reverse voltage well. Aluminum electrolytics will tolerate a small reverse voltage and can "heal" themselves if the voltage is corrected, but it is better use an unpolarized cap it that application.

If you are working with ideal components, the polarity does not matter.

Comment: Actually, this is a theoretical question and I just wanted to know whether the polarity(positive and negative charge is on which side) is maintained irrespective of the current direction. Also, note that the charge was zero initially.

Comment: No, the voltage on the capacitor will reverse. Some people just like drawing polarized caps everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment has the + and - signs near the capacitor to help you assign a direction to the current and voltage across the capacitor.

If they've drawn a polarized cap in your assignment, that's an error. This circuit is mostly unpolarized: The voltage will swing similarly above and below zero.

Things are a little bit asymmetrical because things die out quite rapidly with the component values given. But the initial and biggest excursion will be to put a negative voltage on your capacitor. Not ideal for a polarized one. As uhours already noted, a small voltage does not immediately lead to explosions....

Comment: Actually the - sign just indicates that the terminal is curved because I could not find the symbol. And the current direction and magnitude are initial conditions